# How to select data from xml file by compare attribute of xml file?

Tags: php, xml

here is my xml file note.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<agents>
    <agent>
    <id>1</id>
    <image> img/primary-nav-logo.png</image>
    <name>Tommy Jenkin</name>
    <company>CJenkins Insurance</company>
    <street>Insurance150 S State Stree</street>
    <city>Linkend</city>
    <phone>(773) 561-4331</phone>
    </agent>
    <agent>
    <id>2</id>
    <image> img/primary-nav-logo.png</image>
    <name>Tommy Jenkin</name>
    <company>CJenkins Insurance</company>
    <street>Insurance150 S State Stree</street>
    <city>Linkend</city>
    <phone>(773) 561-4331</phone>
    </agent>
</agents>
```

and i have to print xml record of id 1 and i have write code in php like this

```
<?php
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("note.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
    foreach($xml->xpath('//agent') as $item) { 
    $row = simplexml_load_string($item->asXML());
    $v = $row->xpath('//id[. ="1"]');
    if($v[0]){ 
        print $item->id; 
        print $item->image; 
        print $item->name; 
        print $item->company; 
        print $item->street; 
        print $item->city;
        print $item->phone; 
    }
    else{
        echo 'No records';
    }
?>
```

please suggest me where i am wrong

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to call `$item->asXML()` since `$item` is already a SimpleXML object. And you don't have to loop over your array since you can query the necessary agent directly. Try this:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("note.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$agent = $xml->xpath('//agent[id=1]');
if (!empty($agent)) {
    $item = $agent[0];
    print $item->id;
    print $item->image;
    print $item->name;
    print $item->company;
    print $item->street;
    print $item->city;
    print $item->phone;
} else {
    echo 'No records';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are missing the closing bracket of `foreach` loop.

Second, you can do this with xPath itself.

Look at this code:

```
<pre><?php
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("note.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
    $item = $xml->xpath('//agents/agent[id=1]')[0];
    if($item!=null){
        print_r($item);
    }else{
        echo "No Records";
    }
?></pre>
```